# How to make the c code compiled?

Tags: c, linux

Here is a sample `c` code related to `stat.h`. `bits/stat.h` that mentioned `"Never include <bits/stat.h> directly; use <sys/stat.h> instead."`. However `struct stat` is defined in `bits/stat.h`, and `int __xstat (...)` is defined in `sys/stat.h`. The code won't compile with any one of headers or even both of them. How to make it copiled while only changing the `#include ...` without changing any one of the functions?

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <bits/stat.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>


int stat_1(char *filename, struct stat *stat_buf)
{
  return __xstat(1, filename, stat_buf);  //  extern int __xstat (...) defined in sys/stat.h
}

char * test(const char *filename) {
    char *result;
    stat stat_buf;        //  struct stat defined in bits/stat.h

    printf("DO something here");

    if ( stat_1(filename, &sbuf) == -1 ) {
        printf("DO something here");
    }

    return result;
}


int main() {
    const char *fileName = "file.txt";
    test(fileName);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What errors do you get when `bits/stat.h` is not included (add it to your question)?

Comment: Note that header files in a "bits" directory (like `<bits/stat.h>`) are *internal* and *private* and should not be included directly. Same with symbols starting with double underscore (like `__xstat`), they are internal and private to the library implementation. Why do you want to use it? What is the purpose of your program?

Comment: the posted code causes the C compiler (in this case `gcc`) to output numerous warning and even a few error messages

Comment: the output streams, like `stdout`, are buffered.  so you 'should' force a 'flush' operation so the output is immediately passed to the terminal.  For `printf()` the easiest way to do that is have a '\n' at the end of the format string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be calling `stat` see  https://linux.die.net/man/2/stat. Not __xstat.

Interacting with names that start with `__` is almost always a sign you are doing something wrong. They are under the hood implementation things

Answer (score 1):

For `stat` and its associated struct, you should likely be `include`ing:

```
   #include <sys/types.h>
   #include <sys/stat.h>
   #include <unistd.h>
```